# Multiple root nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am having an XML file with multiple root nodes. I want each and every root node to be stored in seperate record in database. Also while storing in DB I want to validate it with schema and if it is valid fetch some values from the tags there and store it. Please help me in this.

SAMPLE XML file format:

```
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
<Papermail><tags>     </tags></papermail>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with xml too much it can have multiple root nodes? I don't think so..

Comment: Well-formed XML does not have multiple root nodes.

Comment: this is not valid xml my friend

Comment: 1. Ask whoever returns xml to format it properly. 2. Simply add root node

Answer (score 4):

Construct an `XmlReader` with its [`ConformanceLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to `Fragment`. With that, you can now normally iterate through each top-level element. This setting tells the XML reader that there doesn't have to be a single root node. From there, you can do whatever you want with the XML. Or you can even read the top-level elements into `XmlDocument`'s with the [`ReadSubtree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, use XPath, deserialize the XML, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered wrapping the text from the file when you load it with a "root" element.

```
<root>
    <Papermail>
        <tag...
    </Papermail>
</root>
```

This way you can store invalid XML on the file system, but when you load it up and wrap it, it becomes valid XML which you can validate and work with.

Comment: _Have you considered_ is not an answer to his specific question. this should be a commant

Comment: Hmmm... Where I come from this turn of phrase is simply a polite way of instruction... Also... Since this is a solution to the problem he is having I do not feel it should be a comment.